# How to make virtualenv to use the last version of distribute by default?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I often use virtualenv to keep right version of dependancies installed for a project.

```
virtualenv apps --distribute
```

The problem is that when using that, virtualenv keep installing distribute==0.6.19

I need each time to run first :

```
pip install distribute -U
```

Why is that and how can I make it install directly the right version of distribute ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a similar question about updating pip on the [python-virtualenv](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/python-virtualenv/Px2TPhMZ_Zg/discussion) list. I've repeated here for convenience:

If you are using a recent virtualenv you can also use `--extra-search-dir` option to point to an alternate directory containing the `distribute` package you wish to install. This is documented here:

http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html#the-extra-search-dir-option

User-provided extra-search-dir paths have precedence over the "builtin" search paths, so you should be able to achieve what you want

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to upgrade `virtualenv` :

```
sudo aptitude remove python-virtualenv python-pip
sudo easy_install pip virtualenv
```

Then you've got distribute==0.6.24 installed by default.